# Почему не подключается картинка в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Почему не подключается картинка в phpstorm?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Со слешом: `/Img/tint.jpg` нет ошибки?

Comment: ТС, если добавите `../` в начале, то вам станет доступен список изображений, однако лучше использовать относительные ссылки, а не абсолютные, в любом случае, сработает и так, и эдак.

Comment: Лучше использовать путь относительно текущего файла, вроде `background-image: url("../Img/tint.jpg");`, как предложено в ответе. Если же требуется именно `background-image: url("Img/tint.jpg");`, попробуйте пометить корневую папку проекта как **Resource root** (Mark directory as/Resource root)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это)

```
background-image: url("../Img/tint.jpg");
```

btw, если хочешь сделать картинку "responsive" сделай так:

Фиксирована:

```
background: url("../Img/tint.jpg") center center no-repeat fixed;
```

Не зафиксирована на странице:

```
background: url("../Img/tint.jpg") center center no-repeat;
```